# Cell Fracture, How can I use it properly?

Tags: modeling

I Have 2 models, and when i cell fracture them they always act weird, few of them are missing, and others are just plain weird, here are 2 GIFs describing the Problem:

First one [GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/3oeHLjlFjhb0y9lsL6/fullscreen).

Second one [GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/3oeHLCzAW1X34tEvWE) (The reason why i deleted some models, is because for some reason the un-cell-fractured model appear like 5 times).

Also here are the models:

First one : [image]

Second One:[image]
Here are Screenshots:

First one Transparent : 
[image: Left Right Front And Back View (they are all the same)]
[image: Bottom View]
[image: TopView]

Second one Transparent :
[image: Back View]
[image: Front View]
[image: Left View]
[image: Right View]
[image: Top View]
[image: Bottom View]

Comment: Please show 1 or more screen captures in your question, in addition to the gif references. In Edit Mode Show your model so it can be inspected.  Have you made an effort to ensure your model is [compatible/well made]? Menu/Select by All Trait/Non Manifold .. Loose Geometry may reveal defects.  Also for practice, compare Cell Fracture, with known well made meshes such as Cube and Sphere provided by Blender.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, do you want me to give you a screenshot of the cell fractured model in edit mode?, also i have press CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + M and there was no vertices, also the first model is watertight, also on the cubes and spheres it works perfectly, but sadly it doesn't work on my models

Comment: Non-manifold isn't necessarily not closed mesh, you have non-manifold geometry in the base of the roof - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfV1h.jpg, better dissolve all those edges as they aren't needed there and do it like on the other side. Beauty detail made from cylinders on the screenshot won't work with fracture now as that's intersecting geometry, pointed in the answer. Move those faces so they don't intersect. Then, the object is too big. Scale it down 50 times and work on smaller model, it will be faster. Lastly, fracture building and columns separately, it will be more simple

Comment: I am deleting some comments regarding question features.  You many want to do the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, scaling it down did the trick, on the first model. On the second model i had to do some reworking but then scaling it down worked :), thank you so much, Mr Zak, and atomicbezierslinger :)
P.s: (you don't have to answer this)  is there a way to change fractures/objects amount? so that there are more pieces of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Inspect and Repair your Model**

[image]

- Avoid Overlapping Faces. Avoid Intersecting Faces. All submeshes closed.
- Both Meshes have the same number of vertices.

  - Yellow CubeFit mesh is free from defects.
  - Blue CubeNotFit has overlapping connected submeshes seen in edit mode. Intersecting Faces. This is a defect which can be corrected.

[image]

- Cell Fractures in next layer.

  - CubeFit Succeeds.
  - CubeNotfit Fails to retain shape.

---

[image]

Three crude letter (O)s in 3D , first two same mesh, different colors.  Mesh on left has imperfections. Overlapping faces that are difficult to see by casual inspection. Middle Blue Mesh has imperfect overlapping faces, made easy to see by display feature.  Cell Fracture objects on right are the result of an imperfect Cell Fracture on the Middle object.  This flawed result  should not surprise us since we know the source mesh had flaws.  There is no guarantee you will see a flawed result.

Inspect and  correct your mesh to be more like the CubeFit mesh.

- If your model is in one piece, archive your file. Break one model into many convenient, not difficult pieces, to see which sub mesh fails.
- As stated in the first comment ...  Menu/Select by All Trait/Non Manifold .. Loose Geometry may reveal defects.

Comment: Mr. Zak has informed in a comment ... Scale it down 50 times and work on smaller model, it will be faster.